# binary search on c, the while loop

Tags: c, search, binary

There's something that I don't get with the binary search code on C.

```
int binarySearch(int a[], int n, int x)
{
   int low=0, mid, high=n-1;
   while(low <= high)
   {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (x < a[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (x > a[mid])
         low = mid + 1;
       else
         return mid;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Why does the while loop `while(left<=right)` can't be written:
`while(left<right)`? 
Will this change effect things?

Comment: Without the full code this is hard to talk about.

Comment: Iv'e added the code.

Comment: I have, I can see that it doesn't work but I wanted to understand why, thanks.

Comment: Are you **really** asking "is `<` different than `<=`?"

Comment: @Olaf Well, I can think of algorithms behaving the same with both variants.. So the question is "is the algorithm the same with either `<` or `<=`"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a simple case of

```
int a[1] = {5};
printf("%d\n", binarySearch(a, 1, 5));
```

With `while(low < high)`, code prints -1 (did not find - wrong answer).

With `while(low <= high)`, code prints 0 (found - right answer).

Comment: Simple stepping through the code with an array of one element will certainly show why `<` fails` whereas  `<=` works.

Answer (score 7):

## Part 1 - quick answer to this specific problem

This is not a complete summary of the binary search, but I will put it in short to solve this question. 
The key difference for these two while loop conditions, given 
1. that the `low`(`left`) and `high`(`right`) pointers are updated accordingly. By "accordingly", please see part 3. 
2. given that there is no duplicate in the boundary of `LOW`(`LEFT`) and `HIGH`(`RIGHT`) 
3. given that the target exists in the array 
 
`while(low <= high)` does the search in the range of [`LOW`, `HIGH`], both ends inclusive. 
 
In comparison `while(low < high)` does the binary search in the range [`LOW`, `HIGH`), right/high end exclusive. For binary searches of the target in the upper/right range/part, they always miss checks at the very end/right/high, where the last `low`(`left`) stops. To make the range fully covered, one is usually recommended to make another judgement, based on the last `low`(`left`) pointer.

## Part 2 - general guidelines

General guidelines that might be arbitrary: 
1. when dealing with situations where the target surely exists in the array, and the array for search does not contain duplicates, `while(low <= high)` is preferred 
2. when dealing with situations where target does not surely exist in the array, and the array might contain duplicates, `while(low < high)` is recommended.

## Part 3 - code

`low`(`left`) and `high`(`right`) pointers updated "accordingly"

```
    public int binarySearch(int[] nums, int target){

        int left = 0, right = nums.length - 1;
        // please pay attention to the initial condition of right(ptr)
        while(left <= right){
            // to floor the mid
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

            // to check whether the middle element is equal to the target in every iteration
            if(nums[mid] == target) return mid;
            else if(target > nums[mid]) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

```
    public int binarySearch(int[] nums, int target){
        // please pay attention to the initial condition or the right(ptr)
        int left = 0, right = nums.length;

        while(left < right){
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

            // please pay twice attention to the equality case
            if(target > nums[mid]) {
                left = mid + 1;
             } else {
                right = mid;
             }
        }

        return left;
    }
```

## Part 4 - Variations, slightly more advanced

Warning: Confusions might be caused 
for the type of `while(low <= high)`:

```
    public int binarySearchWithFlooringMid(int[] nums, int target){
        // please pay attention to the initial condition of right(ptr)
        int left = 0, right = nums.length - 1;
        while(left <= right){
            // to floor the mid
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

            // to check whether the middle element is equal to the target in every iteration
            if(nums[mid] == target) return mid;
            else if(target > nums[mid]) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                right = mid;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public int binarySearchWithCeilingMid(int[] nums, int target){
        int left = 0, right = nums.length - 1;
        while(left <= right){
            // to ceil the mid
            int mid = left + (right - left + 1) / 2;

            // to check whether the middle element is equal to the target in every iteration
            if(nums[mid] == target) return mid;
            else if(target > nums[mid]) {
                left = mid;
            } else {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

For the type of `while(low < high)`

```
    public int binarySearchLeftmost(int[] nums, int target){
        int left = 0, right = nums.length;

        while(left < right){
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

            // please pay twice attention to the equality case
            if(target > nums[mid]) {
                left = mid + 1;
             } else {
                 right = mid;
             }
        }

        return left;
    }

    public int binarySearchRightmost(int[] nums, int target){
        int left = 0, right = nums.length;

        while(left < right){
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

            // please pay twice attention to the equality case
            if(target < nums[mid]) {
                right = mid;
            } else {
                left = mid + 1;
            }
        }

        return right - 1;
    }
```

This post does NOT cover all the cases in terms of binary searches. There are much more sophisticated requirements, which I will talk about in more details after mastering them.